# Is Tor reliable on a Windows running in Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, privacy, tor

A friend lent me her netbook, it runs ubuntu but fortunately she has VirtualBox where I can use Windows XP, something that I'm familiar with.

In a few weeks when I give it back I don't want there to be any trace of my browsing activity. What do I need to do to ensure my privacy is a 100%?

Answer (score 3):

Tor hides your traces from outside, but really, it dosen't do anything for what the system stores. The tor browser bundle *shouldn't* store anything, but the fact that its there might be a clue that its been used - especially since it needs an install.

I'd probably just make a fresh copy of the windows XP VM she's using (by exporting and importing it), then deleting it once done - this should keep all your activity to that VM, and everything would be deleted with the VM. I'd also suggest using a 'portable' browser -like [firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable), then deleting the whole folder (preferably securely, with something like [eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/)) if that's not an option. Portable apps are great for leaving a minimal trail on a system.

Comment: Or snapshot => restore snapshot. Of course, if the friend wants to log traffic, she can do so from the host OS...